# Prove that if A × B is uncountable, then at least one of A or B is uncountable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know the Cartesian product of any two countable sets is countable. Also, it is safe to say that the Cartesian product of uncountable sets is uncountable.

I am totally lost on how to prove at least one of A or B is uncountable. I need some suggestions.

Comment: You’ve already proved it. Your first sentence is the contrapositive of the required statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to restate the claim as its own contrapositive, given a fact you said you already know: if they're both countable, then they have a countable Cartesian product.